# Why does `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` with only two points raise OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, covariance

Why doesn't this simple fit work?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
exponential = lambda x, a, b: np.exp(a * x + b)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f=exponential, xdata=[350, 380], ydata=[48, 17], p0=[-0.01, 1])
print("a =", popt[0])
print("b =", popt[1])
```

The output is:

```
python-3.4.4\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py:715:
OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
category=OptimizeWarning)

a = -0.03459958889505575
b = 15.981057124177402
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works but in calculating the pcov:

> If the Jacobian matrix at the solution doesn’t have a full rank, then ‘lm’ method returns a matrix filled with np.inf.

Which is your case and hence you see the warning message.

Comment: @muschL The error is estimated by how far off your fit is from the data points. However an exponential can always perfectly fit two points, therefore there is no good way of estimating the error.